# randomly select one element on every row

Tags: python, pandas

#### Suppose I have pandas dataframe with 3 columns looking like this:

```
     col1     col2     col3
0  banana1  banana2  banana2
1   apple1   apple2   apple3
2  monkey1  monkey2  monkey3
3  iphone1  iphone2  iphone3
4  runner1  runner2  runner3
5     pig1     pig2     pig3
6    wifi1    wifi2    wifi3
7    girl1    girl2    girl3
8     boy1     boy2     boy3
9  couple1  couple2  couple3
```

How can I randomly select 1 out of 3 elements on every row and append it to a new dataframe where I want it to loop N times then move on and append 1 out of 3 elements on a new row and loop it N times?

#### This is a little bit hard to explain so I'd explain by an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': ['banana1', 'apple1', 'monkey1', 'iphone1', 'runner1', 'pig1', 'wifi1', 'girl1', 'boy1', 'couple1'],
        'col2': ['banana2', 'apple2', 'monkey2', 'iphone2', 'runner2', 'pig2', 'wifi2', 'girl2', 'boy2', 'couple2'],
        'col3': ['banana2', 'apple3', 'monkey3', 'iphone3', 'runner3', 'pig3', 'wifi3', 'girl3', 'boy3', 'couple3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2' , 'col3'])
```

So what I want to do is to randomly select either `item1`, `item2` OR `item3` for every row and append it to a new row in a new dataframe, when the 10'th item is selected I want it to start over doing this N times and then move on to a new row in the new dataframe and loop it N times. Eventually ending up with something like this (with randomness):

```
    1       2      3       4       5       6    7     8     9    10       11      12     13      14      15      16   17    18    19   20
    banana3 apple2 monkey1 iphone2 runner2 pig1 wifi2 girl3 boy1 couple1  banana1 apple2 monkey2 iphone3 runner3 pig3 wifi2 girl1 boy1 couple3
    ........................................................................................................................................... 
    ...........................................................................................................................................
    ...........................................................................................................................................
    banana1 apple2 monkey2 iphone3 runner1 pig2 wifi3 girl1 boy3 couple2  banana2 apple1 monkey2 iphone2 runner2 pig1 wifi2 girl3 boy1 couple2
```

In this output the loop I have selected 1/3 on every row looped it 2 times to N rows in the new dataframe.

#### My attempt:

I'd love to do it by a function which will give me the desired output based on n and N.

```
new_df = []

def rand_element_selection(n,N):
    for row in df.iterrows: 
        element_holder = df.sample(1)
        new_df.append(placeholder)
```

`n` and `N` is not defined above because im struggling to move forward..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenation is mainly from [EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36330724/2285236):

```
n=3
N=2
df_list=[]
for i in range(n):
    df_list.append(pd.concat([df.apply(np.random.choice, axis=1) for i in range(N)], ignore_index=True))
new_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True).T
```

Comment: thank you, all the columns are independent of each other as well as the rows.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do this by calling `sample` on `axis=1` and transpose:

```
In [172]:
n=3
N=2
df_list=[]
for i in range(n):
    df_list.append(pd.concat([df.sample(1, axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True) for j in range(N)], axis=1, ignore_index=True))
pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)    

Out[172]:
        0       1        2        3        4     5      6      7     8   \
0  banana2  apple3  monkey3  iphone3  runner3  pig3  wifi3  girl3  boy3   
1  banana2  apple2  monkey2  iphone2  runner2  pig2  wifi2  girl2  boy2   
2  banana2  apple2  monkey2  iphone2  runner2  pig2  wifi2  girl2  boy2   

        9        10      11       12       13       14    15     16     17  \
0  couple3  banana2  apple3  monkey3  iphone3  runner3  pig3  wifi3  girl3   
1  couple2  banana1  apple1  monkey1  iphone1  runner1  pig1  wifi1  girl1   
2  couple2  banana2  apple3  monkey3  iphone3  runner3  pig3  wifi3  girl3   

     18       19  
0  boy3  couple3  
1  boy1  couple1  
2  boy3  couple3
```

Comment: nice answer, however, i might have lacked some information in my question, the randomness of selecting the items should be in rows, row 0 only consists of `item2` row 1 of `item1`, i want the items in the new rows to be totally random so that row 0 can consist of every item i, where i is either 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand can you edit your question with a clear explanation

Comment: `df.apply(np.random.choice, axis=1)` would return a random item selected from each row. You can call df.apply in a loop and concat like @EdChum showed.

Comment: thanks alot for your effort but I'm having trouble explaining it better, sorry. `row0` of the output above only consist of items 2 whereas i'd like it to be random, i.e any item 1,2 or 3 on every col and every row. @ayhan thanks, that randomly select one item, how can I use that in EdChum s code?

Comment: I still don't understand why the above doesn't do what you ask, it randomly selects a value from each row and appends column-wise and repeats this again for each line

Comment: Is it possible to append it row-wise? as it is now, row 0 contains of only item2, row 1 contains of only item1 and row2 only of item2. How can the randomness be totally random for every row and column, in other words, how the columns be independent of each other? in this example item [0,2] is dependent on item [0,1] and so on where [row, col]

Comment: OK I see that the row repeats, I've made a mod which deals with this